# Tracking when a control renders

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, rendering

My end goal is to draw an updated RenderTargetBitmap anytime a specific control renders any updates, which will be sent to a COM object and rendered in another application.

I'm trying to hook onto any event which will let me know that the control, or any of its children, have updated. [My control](https://github.com/ascendedguard/starboard-sc2/blob/master/starboard-sc2/View/ScoreboardControl.xaml) is a mix of databound text and image fields, and gradients that have ColorAnimations applied to them.

**Is there any way to know a visual control (and it's children) have changed?** I've tried listening to `OnVisualChildrenChanged`, `ArrangeOverride`, `ParentLayoutInvalidated`, and `OnRender`, none of which are fired when a databound child is rendered.

An initial thought was to simply listen to the databound fields in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` object, however the ColorAnimation means all the frames of the control won't be properly captured.

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into d3d which is used by WPF "the hard way". But since you are looking for some straight forward way directly from your C# code I came across something interesting.

If I am not mistaken this will let you hook into the d3d surface of WPF in a very simple way and let you know every time the surface is rendered – so you can capture only on updates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx

Disclaimer: Never did try it out and the last time I piloted a compiler is a long time ago-:)

(Will, Thanks for your contributions on XSplit testing)